# Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message 'Comments starting with '#' are deprecated

Tags: zend-framework, deprecated

I have developed a web application and deployed the same under php version 5.2.13 but when i shifted the same to server having PHP Version 5.3.6 it started to give me the error

> Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message 'Comments
>   starting with '#' are deprecated in ...

Please suggest any workaround to run the same without downgrading the php version.

Comment: What do you mean by "run the same with downgrading"? :?

Comment: How about just replacing the `#`'s in your config file with symbol `;`? As suggested here: http://azitech.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/php-comments-starting-with-are-deprecated/

Comment: corrected : Please suggest any workaround to run the same without downgrading the php version.

Comment: Hi fireeyedboy, you are right but the error is coming at so many places and we can go and change # at all the places, the files are quite large in number.

Answer (score 6):

The clue is in the error. You can no longer comment out lines in an ini file using a hash, use a semi-colon instead. If you simply change this in whichever ini file it's complaining about the error should disappear.

Edit: Since the error is coming from Zend_Config I'm assuming it's an ini file it's complaining about. If it's a PHP script then use `//` to comment out the line instead.